# populating a specific cell in dataGridView from database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 14 columns in dataGridView But I want to populate the first column of the dataGridView from the names of fee types in database. But it gives me ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Here is my code.

```
 myDatabase dbOperation = new myDatabase();
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
 table = dbOperation.select("name from feetypes");
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["feeType"].Value = table.Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: How many row are there in the database, if it's > 14 then you might get a ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Could you make a join from the database when you are querying the database for the first population?

Comment: rows are less than 14.

Comment: You need to add the Rows to your GridView at runtime. add this in loop -> `dataGridView1.Rows.Add();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :**  you are trying to access the `Rows` without creating them.

**Solution :** You need to add the Rows to your `DataGridView` at runtime.

Try This:

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
   try
   {
      dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["feeType"].Value = table.Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
      dataGridView1.Rows.Add(); //add this
   }
```

Comment: You are Welcome dear :) glad to be help of you.